# What is the easiest way to trigger a shell script on my local machine and get its output

Tags: shell, node.js

Say I have a script.sh as:

```
echo $1
echo $2
echo $3
```

And I have a web page served by node.js at *localhost:3000/page*

I would like to create the page like this ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a9Lp2jr6/)):

```
script.sh <input type="text" name="param1" />
<input type="text" name="param1" /> <input type="text" name="param1" />  
<button>fire!</button>
<hr>
<p> Output </p>
<textarea></textarea>
```

When I clicked the fire button, the output will be showed in the `<textarea>` element. I shall be the three parameters that I input.

Comment: Low effort answer: http://jaketrent.com/post/run-shell-script-nodejs/

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103735/run-shell-script-with-node-js-childprocess